# Sonar sensor in ROS

Tags: ros, sonar, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello to everybody,

I have to ask a suggestion. Is there any implementation of sonar sensor in ROS?

I need an height estimator for my simulated quadrotor (it has to be external to IMU equipped on the quadrotor) in ROS. So, I thought to a sonar sensor.

I know that I could subscribe to all model state topic and get the z but this might be a source of error. Think about a quadrotor at 1m of height in hovering. If there is an object under it (own height 0.2m) the absolute height is again 1m instead of 1-0.2 = 0.8m that a sonar will have as output. In the meantime, if I check this constraint it is a source of error. Think about quadrotor with 15deg of roll. The height is not 1m but something more.

So, I need this kind of error. I also thought also to a range finder sensor (like Hokuyo) that I know there is already in ROS with a range really small.
Has anyone tried this solution? In this way, I might be sure that it works.
If there is a sonar implementation, this would be great!

Thanks a lot for any reply. Best regards,

Neostek

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37559/sonar-sensor-in-ros/) by [Neostek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2231/neostek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2012-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello there is a ros implementation of SRF08 sonar sensors
available on http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/htm/srf08tech.shtml

then here is the ros package of this sensor

https://launchpad.net/usbi2c-ros-pkg

you may give it a try :)

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1